# How to float part of a nav bar left and other part right

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to float a logo to the left side of a `nav` bar, and have the text float to the right of the `nav` bar. I am trying to accomplish this through bootstrap. I have tried adding float and text align classes to outer `divs` and specific elements. I have shown my code below, keep in mind it is not meant to be run.

```js
//not meant to be run
//bootstrap is not hooked up
```

```html
    <div class = "row col-12">
    <div class = "float-left col-3">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class = "float-right col-9">

    <nav class = "nav text-right">
<a class = "homen" href="home.html">Home</a>
<a class = "aboutn" href="about.html">About</a>
<a class = "teamn" href="team.html">Team</a>
<a class = "contactn" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flexbox utilitys. For example use justify-content-end on the collapse menu:

```
<html>

<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Also note, as of Bootstrap 5 ml-auto has been replaced with ms-auto

Answer (score 0):

This is from official Bootstrap documentation. It uses `display: flex` design and if you want to align menu to left again, you can change `mr-auto` with `me-auto`. This is also responsive code with hidden button which can only come with mobile screens.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```